# Mediation with multilevel data in R with lavaan

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, mediation, lavaan

I am familiarizing myself with SEM and the lavaan package for R bc I would like to run a mediation analysis. My problem is that the data I have is nested and currently I don't see how I could do a mediation analysis on this type of data using lavaan.

The data is from a cognitive psychology study where participants recall answers on a memory test for questions presented in a study phase. The data is clustered by participant (ID ~ 50) and by the topic of the questions (topics = 8). The outcome variable is recall (0/1) the predictor is a variable reflecting if the question is related to a previous reading (0/1) and the mediator is a curiosity rating (1-5). The data is trial level (80 responses/participant), clustered by participants and question topic (all participants read all the questions - 10 resps/topic).

How would you implement a mediation analysis on this data using lavaan, taking into account the clustering of the data? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to test the mediation at the level-2, level-1 or both?
You have here an example of testing an homologous model at both levels:

```r
      model <- '
        level: 1
            # direct effect
                 y3 ~ c*x3
               # mediator
                 y2 ~ a*x3
                 y3 ~ b*y2
               # indirect effect (a*b)
                 ab := a*b
               # total effect
                 total := c + (a*b)
        level: 2
                    # direct effect
                 y3 ~ c*x3
               # mediator
                 y2 ~ a*x3
                 y3 ~ b*y2
               # indirect effect (a*b)
                 ab := a*b
               # total effect
                 total := c + (a*b)
    '
      
    fit <- sem(model = model, data = Demo.twolevel, cluster = "cluster")
    summary(fit, std=T)
```

Comment: thank you! the syntax is fine, although it turned out that lavaan can not handle binary and ordinal variables yet :/ trying mplus now

Comment: Yes, that's true. Please check the solution as verified if it solves the general problem

Comment: @Sinval Thank you for the code. Could you maybe show what the model would look like if I am only interested in Level 1, because all my variables are at Level 1 but still come from repeated measures?

Comment: So, do you want a level 1 only mediation? You just remove the paths that are not of interest from level 2.

Answer (score 0):

Like you correctly figured out, lavaan unfortunately only supports multilevel models with continuous data and 2 levels at the moment. Therefore, both your outcome variable 'recall (0/1)' and the predictor variable 'previous reading (0/1)' cannot be appropriately modeled using lavaan currently. Furthermore, your proposed model represents a 3-level framework to me: Level 3: Participants; Level 2: Topics; Level 1: Responses.

However, using the mediate package might be a possible choice for you, if you want to avoid paying multiple hundred dollars for proprietary software like Mplus. With the *mediate* package you can use binary data, but only modelling of two levels is supported.

This is the basic syntax for multilevel mediation using both *lme4* and *mediation* libraries. x represents the treatment, y the outcome and m your mediator.

```
library(lme4)
library(mediation)
model1 <- lmer(m ~ x  + (1|participant), data=df)
model2 <- lmer(y ~ m + x + (1|participant), datas=df)
mediation <- mediate(model1, model2, treat = "x", mediator = "m", sims = 100)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/351931)